# Hypernym for "day", "month", "week", "year"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I would like to know if there is a single-word hypernym for *day, month, week* and *year*.

Comment: Have you checked past questions on ELU? And elsewhere, esp., online?

Comment: Yes I have checked

Comment: Er... interval? Duration?

Comment: Time interval (may be, although it's 2 words), duration - aswers the question how long, I am looking for something that answers the question when

Comment: But "day", "month", "week" or "year" do not answer the question "When?"

Comment: I meant situations like these: When? - in a month. When? - 5 days ago

Comment: Do you mean "For how long?"?

Comment: Question is incomplete as evidenced by repeated clarifications attempted in comment. Question should be closed until edited to make it clear what is wanted.

Comment: Read [Fillmore on 'Time'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf) in the _[Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html)._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Time period](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time+period) is general enough:

> **time period** *n.* an amount of time

Comment: I thought of this one, just wasn't sure enough. Thanks

Comment: Too general perhaps?  'Two weeks' is a time period also.  But I understood the question to mean the individual units of measurement.

Answer (score 8):

Their hypernym would be based in their singular aspect of similarity — into what set can they all fit. So words like *time* and *span* (or even *time span*) would do the trick assuming you mean a duration. If you mean a specific period then try, um, *period*.

Comment: Timespan is often spelled without the offending period: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/timespan

Comment: @WayfaringStranger *Time-span* is only, ever, and always spelt without any offending period.  However, it is oft spelled with a graceful hyphen.

Comment: @tchrist  Oops, meant offending space, which would make it two words.