# Word for each component of a time-stamp

Tags: single-word-requests, time

If I have been presented with a time-stamp in the 24-hour format: 12:24:33 (hh:mm:ss)

Is there a word to address a component of this? By a component, I mean each value between 2 delimiters (only the minutes or only the hour etc.)
With reference to the above example:

> 12, 24, 33 are all ____ of the time-stamp.

Comment: could you use digits? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit

Comment: @bookmanu But digits would mean singular digits won't it? If someone used "digits of a DateTime", I would think they meant each digit individually (like "2", "0", "1" etc.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about naming elements in a class used in programming, which is explicitly out of our site scope according  to our Help Center.

Comment: @tchrist while the question did originate from a programming class, I am looking for usages to address this term in spoken English. I have updated the question to a ke it sound less like a Programming related question.

Comment: Unless you are looking for a linguistics-based answer, check the thesaurus for *parts, pieces, bits, elements*.

Comment: Consider also _segments_, _aspects_, or _[units](https://www.basic-mathematics.com/units-of-time.html)_.

Comment: They're units of time, hours, minutes, seconds, the colons separate the different units of time. Edit: if you want a class or members name for your program you can call them time units.

Comment: They are time literals. Literals are constant values of variables. Here, variables are hh, mm, ss.

Comment: "Is there a word to address a component of this?" Well, yes. You only just used it yourself right there.

Comment: And I think everyone else's suggestions are inferior to what you yourself instinctively picked.

Comment: Question is closely related to: [Hypernym for "day", "month", "week", "year"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95388/hypernym-for-day-month-week-year).

Comment: @tchrist unleash the titan.

Comment: @RegDwigнt the original question referred to both date and time (a datetime) and for that case I felt the word "component" would be inferred as that date or time part and not the individual bits of them.

Comment: I'm sorry to pint out that English isn't seriously interested in that. Kris (below) seems to have explained all that matters and still, d'you not think that's more to do with physics or filing than English?

Comment: Notations? That's what these people say: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Components** of a timestamp:

[image]

> Zone and offset information are two more useful components of timestamps that many may not know about.

(Sai Peddy, Java 8 DateTime, [Medium](https://medium.com/@saipeddy/java-8-datetime-a20de1b804b8))

*See also:*
Db2 [**TIMESTAMP_FORMAT**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) on IBM Knowledge Center

[image]

Comment: While this mentions what each component is specifically called, I was looking for a word to collectively address all of these components.

Comment: It does not "mention what each component is specifically called." The "components" make up the timestamp.

Comment: Please do not conflate using both "each" and "collectively" -- they do not mean the same.

Comment: A timestamp is made up of various "components". *Each* component has a name which your answer lists. But If I were to address *all* of these components with one word *collectively* (like I use the word *components* in this comment), what would I call them? Please see the incomplete example sentence in my question.

Comment: That is the answer: *component* is the word.

Comment: Yeah components seems right if I was only talking in the context of time, but if it were a fully formed DateTime as in your example, I am not sure if ***components*** would be understood as each number (Day, Month, Hour etc.) or as each whole unit (Time, Date, Zone etc). But that seems to be the best of the lot at the moment.

Comment: Please see my most recent edit including reference to IBM Knowledge Center Db2 pages.

Comment: I haven't consider voting, but I disagree with you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well! I am bit late to answer this question. Actually, a word to collectively address all of these components is called Time literal  [wiki](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/literal)

## time literals

> A date literal is a fixed expression that represents a relative range of time, such as last month, this week, or next year.

In computer science, literals are fix values of a given datatype.
Further reading: [Time Literals](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01031.0400/doc/html/asc1252676795351.html)

Comment: Please see "Literals" (ibid.) before reaching "Time Literals."

Comment: @Kris literal (plural literals)(programming) A value, as opposed to an identifier, written into the source code of a computer program.
Synonym: literal constant wiki - https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/literal   hope this helps :)

Comment: @Kris I still haven't considered voting on your answer.  When I do, I will inform you. Also,  OP is not happy with you answer.

Answer (score -2):

These can also be called ***fields***.

Oxford has this definition:

> 2.1 *Computing* A part of a record, representing an item of data.

As for usage in the field<sup>1</sup>, Lindsay Holmwood says in [Timestamp Limitations When Processing RFC3164 Formatted Logs](http://fractio.nl/2007/11/08/rfc3164-timestamp-limitations-when-processing-logs/):  (*emphasis mine*)

> According to RFC3164, the TIMESTAMP field in the HEADER section of a syslog packet is in the format of “Mmm dd hh:mm:ss” (e.g. Oct 11 22:14:15). Astute readers will note that there is no year ***field*** in the timestamp.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>*a different field ;-)*</sup></sub>